# Conditional HTTP redirection based on host name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
RewriteRule index.php$ setup.php

RewriteEngine On
Redirect /setup /setup.php
```

I need to change this condition. How do I know where the HTTP_HOST is registered?
By inserting as below I don't get the desired result. I always see the index.php

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

If I make the request I get the site name, in this case X.X.X.104, I would like to get X.X.X.104 transformed into X.X.X.104/setup.php

Comment: Do you want to know about the internals of mod_rewrite or solve some problem with your rules? `HTTP_HOST` corresponds to the `Host` header sent by browser.

Comment: Solve the problem with the rules. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, some remarks:

- `RewriteEngine On` takes effect for the entire request, there's no need to repeatedly enable it.
- `Redirect` directive is provided by [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) rather than mod_rewrite. It's mean to generate redirection headers, so the browser loads a different URL. For instance, browser asks for `http://example.com` and it's redirected to `https://www.example.com`.
- `RewriteRule` directive is provided by ([mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)) and it's meant to generate internal redirections, so the browser receives a response in the original URL requested. For instance, browser asks for `https://example.com/products/31416-bluetooth-speakers` and gets a response there, but it's internally handled by `https://www.example.com/products.php?id?31416`.

To get an HTTP redirection in both cases (e.g. [301 Moved Permanently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301)) you can either use `mod_alias` or append the `redirect` flag to `RewriteRule`. Since you also need to filter by host name, second option is probably more straightforward. I've tweaked the rule to avoid infinite redirections and also include requests with path `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
RewriteRule ^index\.php$|^/?$ /setup.php [redirect]

RewriteRule ^setup/?$ /setup.php [redirect]
```

Please note I've removed leading `/` because `RewriteBase` defaults to `/` in `.htaccess` files. You'd need to add them if you were setting this configuration in main `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: It does not work. `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` always answers X.X.X.104

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Why would anything discussed here cause `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` to display anything else than the `Host` HTTP header supplied by browser? Are you trying to redirect to an entirely different site, like ask for `http://X.X.X.104` and get sent to `http://localhost`?

Comment: I would like `X.X.X.104` to become `X.X.X.104/setup.php`.

While in case it's in localhost it doesn't change.

Instead I always get `X.X.X.104` (answers /index.php)

Comment: If you type `http://localhost` in your browser it's impossible to get redirected to `http://X.X.X.104` with the code involved in this question. If that happens, you have some additional undisclosed arrangements, such as a proxy server or additional redirections set up elsewhere. Or maybe you need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough. They are two different connections. If I access from the browser inside the device where the site is located, I would like to see the `localhost/index.php`. While instead if I access that address from another device I would like the accesser to have as response instead of `X.X.X.X./index.php` --> `X.X.X.X./setup.php`

Comment: That's what happens in my machine. What part is not working, the localhost redirection, the other redirection, or the localhost exception? I don't know why it won't work for you anyway, sorry.

Comment: I find it absurd too, since I had already used it... Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: So, 3 things needed. None of them work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252548/discussion-between-nicolaita-and-alvaro-gonzalez).

Comment: I finally did this and it works `.$localhost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if ($localhost != 'localhost'){
  header('Location: /setup.php');
}`
The mystery remains that .htaccess doesn't work

Comment: Are you using Apache in the first place? `.htaccess` will be ignored by other servers like Nginx or IIS.